# Getting error while trying to publish/ deploy .sppkg on AppCatalog using Publish-PnPApp

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, spfx

I am trying to upload .sppkg file to App Catalog using SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module. I am able to add the ".sppkg" file to AppCatalog but getting error when I am trying to deploy/publish.

Error

```
Publish-PnPApp : {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891,System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Deployment can only be done in the context of an app catalog web"}}}
At line:1 char:1
Publish-PnPApp -Identity $App.ID -Scope Site
  + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Publish-PnPApp], Exception
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Apps.PublishApp
```

Below is my script that I am using for uploading the .sppkg file:

```
$AppCatalogURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/"
$AppFilePath = "D:\AzureDevOps\sfpxProject\sharepoint\solution"
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist username, (Get-Content "D:\TestScript\svc.CredNew.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $AppFilePath
#Connect to SharePoint Online App Catalog site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AppCatalogURL -Credentials $Cred
cd D:\AzureDevOps\sfpxProject\sharepoint\solution
#Add App to App catalog
$App = Add-PnPApp -Path $items.name -Scope Site -Overwrite
#Deploy App to the Site
Publish-PnPApp -Identity $App.ID -Scope Site
```

The id that i am using to deploy is having Service support admin Role in Office365

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: A simple question - do you have app catalog _on your site_? Looks like you don't. I mean, you specify to publish to a _site_ catalog and not to the default catalog. For this to happen, this site catalog must exist (you need to create one if you don't have it). Please note that your settings are not the default (by default, applications are published to *global* app catalog)

Comment: Yeah Nikolay. I have the the app catalog for my site. I am trying to automate sharepoint deployment using azure devops. I have tried the below script but getting error:

Comment: $AppCatalogURL = "https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/****/AppCatalog"

$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist ******, (Get-Content "D:\TestScript\svc.CredNew.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)

Connect-PnPOnline $AppCatalogURL -Credentials $Cred

$OutPath = "D:\AzureDevOps\sfpxProject\sharepoint\solution"

$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $OutPath

$App = Add-PnPApp -Path $items.name -Scope Site -Overwrite

Comment: Add-PnPApp : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:1 char:8
+ $App = Add-PnPApp -Path $items.name -Scope Site -Overwrite
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPApp], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Apps.AddApp

Comment: Okay, looks like permission issue then.. Do you have the user whos credentials you are using for the deployment added as admin for your target site?